# How can I manage a WinForms .NET component from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, winforms

I have a WinForms .NET component that can render and save JPG images. How can I make it work on my ASP.NET website each time a visitor requests a page?

1. Do I need write a web service?
2. Do I need to run a winforms app on the server and interact with it?
3. Do I need to host it on a separate ASP.NET page and query it to render and save new images?

Thanks.

EDIT: I am looking for a solution that **doesn't** need any control to be downloaded but simply a page refresh to display the new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to expose a .NET WinForm control as an ActiveX control in any HTML or aspx page

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/htmlwincontrol.aspx

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, this requires the website visitor to download the control, isn't it?